# LdapName JSON serializer

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am trying to create a REST service that returns (javax.naming.ldap.)LdapName objects in JSON (using jackson).
The serializer goes as below.
However, I get an InvalidDefinitionException that says *No serializer found for class javax.naming.ldap.LdapName$1 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer*

```
@JsonComponent
public abstract class LdapNameSerializer  extends JsonSerializer<LdapName> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(LdapName value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("dn", value.toString());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
} // class LdapNameSerializer
```

Can somone tell me what I am doing wrong ?
Thxs in adv.

Comment: I find it a bit odd that you want to serialize `javax.naming.ldap.LdapName`, rather than providing your own output format for the data you're interested in. Especially if you get confused about inner classes.